# trouble with & in a url for .htaccss

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following line in my .htaccess file that works great unless there is a & in the file name

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*).jpg$ redirect_images.php?size=large&old=$1.jpg [L]
```

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)&(.*).jpg$ redirect_images.php?size=large&old=$1%26$2.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*).jpg$ redirect_images.php?size=large&old=$1.jpg [L]
```

but old returns with $16$2 when reading the variable.

I have also tired

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*).jpg$ redirect_images.php?size=large&old=$1.jpg [B,L]
```

after some searching on the internet but that results in a 500 Error.  Any ideas?

Comment: the `B` flag works on my machine. When you get the 500 error, what do the logs say ? You can also check the debug logs for the rewrite module: ([RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2, [LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4).

Comment: `B` should not cause 500. Check your Apache error.log file

Comment: This server is a pain.  It gives me 500 error for just about anything and no error log like most,  I ended up fixing the problem by redirecting all urls for unfound files to a php file and use substr(urldecode($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]),1); to get the url requested

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping it with a backslash

So `&` becomes `\&`